# Bind variables in SQL Developer - data type

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, bind-variables

I'm trying to use bind variables in SQL Developer. The problem is that I can't set the variable to type `NUMBER` - it's type is always set to `VARCHAR2(32)`:

```
create view test1v as select 1 as abc from dual;
VARIABLE X NUMBER;
EXEC :X := 1;
explain plan for SELECT /*TOTO7*/ * FROM test1v where rownum = :X;
```

[image]

I'm using SQL Developer 17.4.0.355

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is type number - at least if you run a real statement, rather than just explaining one. As a quick check, if you do:

```
EXEC :X := 'X';
```

then you'll get "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error" as expected.

The confusion, I think, is that you're assuming the `:X` in the explained query is making use of the local bind variable you're declared. But you can use `:1` or `:Z` for the `explain plan` and it will still work and show the same information.

When you explain first, the bind value isn't captured and it doesn't know the bind type, so it defaults to `varchar2`:

```
explain plan for SELECT /*ABC1*/ * FROM test1v where rownum = :X;

Explained.

select sbc.datatype_string, sbc.was_captured, sbc.value_string
from gv$sql s
join gv$sql_bind_capture sbc on sbc.sql_id = s.sql_id
where s.sql_text like '%ABC1%';

DATATYPE_STRING WAS_CAPTURED VALUE_STRING
--------------- ------------ ------------
VARCHAR2(32)    NO
```

If you actually run the query, rather than just explaining it, the bind value is now captured - both versions appear:

```
SELECT /*ABC1*/ * FROM test1v where rownum = :X;

       ABC
----------
         1

select sbc.datatype_string, sbc.was_captured, sbc.value_string
from gv$sql s
join gv$sql_bind_capture sbc on sbc.sql_id = s.sql_id
where s.sql_text like '%ABC1%';

DATATYPE_STRING WAS_CAPTURED VALUE_STRING
--------------- ------------ ------------
VARCHAR2(32)    NO                       
NUMBER          YES          1
```

I suspect that you ran a query normally, then added a comment to be able to find its SQL ID and bind info; but in doing so you made it a *different* query, which was parsed separately, and the bind wasn't captured at that point. But you see the same thing if you run the query first - the `number` version is captured first but the explain plan version still gets a `varchar2` entry.